# Fetch User Shipping Address from Stripe `PlatformPayButton`

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, applepay

I am trying to implement Apple Pay checkout with Stripe using the provided React Native `PlatformPayButton` component. One of the required fields in our checkout flow is a shipping address -- which I set as a required field in the initial call of `createPlatformPayPaymentMethod`.

I understand that there is a prop `onShippingContactSelected` that I can use to try to get the shipping contact that the user selects. However, when utilizing this prop, the callback never gets called and the Apple Pay sheet hands on Processing then eventually cancels the payment. See the code below:

```
 <PlatformPayButton
    onPress={handleBuyNow}
    type={PlatformPay.ButtonType.Buy}
    appearance={PlatformPay.ButtonStyle.Black}
    borderRadius={4}
    style={styles.applePayButton}
    onShippingContactSelected={event => {
       console.log('Contact: ', event.shippingContact);

       updatePlatformPaySheet({
       applePay: {
         cartItems: [
           {
             label: 'item',
             amount: String('10'),
             paymentType: PlatformPay.PaymentType.Immediate,
           },
         ],
         shippingMethods: shippingMethods,
         errors: [],
       },
     });
     }}
  />
```

When running the app, the `console.log('Contact: ', event.shippingContact);` never gets called and the Apple Pay process hangs (in the way that I assume happens when you do not use `updatePlatformPaySheet` as recommended. **Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to properly implement this callback to get the shipping info?** Thanks!

Comment: What do you have under `requiredShippingAddressFields`?

Comment: @karbi I have `[PlatformPay.ContactField.PostalAddress]` as the value for `requiredShippingAddressFields`

Comment: Can you also share your code that calls `confirmPlatformPayPayment`? Your code for `onShippingContactSelected` looks almost identical to mine, and the callback is working in my integration so it's gotta be something else that's the problem